# How to toggleClass when resizing window?

Tags: jquery

I'm want to have divs that sticks on scroll but stops at bottom at the end of parent div, this works fine. And when the window is less than 700px I want the sticky class removed, this works fine to. The problem I have now is to add the sticky class again when the window is bigger than 700 again. How do I toggle these classes so they appear again when the window gets bigger?

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m6jfyh9L/2/

I'm using the stickem.js library from here https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-Stickem/blob/master/jquery.stickem.js

The code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $('.container').stickem();

    var window = $(window).width();

     if (window<700) 
       $("div").removeClass("stickem");
       $("div").removeClass("stickem-container");
       $("div").removeClass("stickit");
       $("div").removeClass("stickit-end");

});
```

Comment: Can't this be done using CSS [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) ? any reason you want to do it via JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).resize(function() {
    if(false == $('.selector').hasClass('sticky') && $(window).width() >= 700) {
      $('.selector').addClass('sticky');
    }

    if(true == $('.selector').hasClass('sticky') && $(window).width() < 700) {
      $('.selector').removeClass('sticky');
    }
  });
});
```

Haven't tested it yet. Just make sure you can select the element you want to add or remove your sticky class to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
     if($(this).width()>700)
        $('yourDiv').addClass('sticky');
     else
        $('yourDiv').removeClass('sticky');
});
```

Comment: Anytime.. happy coding.. :)